# GitLab CI CD - Get variables from external project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So, I am setting up a deployment strategy and I wanted to see if this was possible. I have scoured the documentation, and I can't find anywhere that is says it is NOT possible, but I also haven't found anything saying that it IS possible.

To keep things simple, here is a simplified version of what I'm trying

I have a group and within that group there are projects:

MasterGroup/project_1
MasterGroup/project_2

I was hoping that project_1 could be the store of variables, common tasks (stages).

Then in project_2, I can include yml files from project_1.

I can do this without difficulty, but the problem is, the "include" statement does not bring project_1 variables with it.

Is there a way to also include the variables of the project? I see that i can add them as environment variables withing the Runner, but I wanted to try to keep things simple first.

Comment: You can define the variables at the "MasterGroup" level, like that all the project within that group can access the same variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define environment variables on the group level:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#group-level-environment-variables

These variables should then be visible as inherited variables in both project_1 and project_2.

It is also possible to set variables in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file of project_1, that can be included in project_2. They have an example of how it works, and also shows how to override the variables if that is wanted:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#overriding-external-template-values

But if you like to store secret things, it is better to use the group level environment variables.